# How to use promises in Angular and get rid of using timeouts

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, angular-promise

I am trying to wait for the server to return the some data and then do another callback. This is my code

```
commonApp.factory('replyMessageFactory', ['$q', '$http', '$log', function ($q, $http, $log) {
var factoryObj = {};

factoryObj.send = function (obj) {
    var req = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: "/api/ThreadMessage",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        },
        data: obj
    }

    return $http(req);
}
return factoryObj;
}
]);
```

I am calling this factory method as below

```
scope.sendReply = function () {
     updateModel();
     var replyModelValue = scope.replyModel;
     replyMessageFactory.send(scope.replyModel).then(function (data) {
             scope.clear();
             scope.updateThread(replyModelValue);
     });
}
```

The thing is that I am not getting the latest data from the back end. If I add timeout then it works. Could it also be because of the back end?

My backend api is this

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post(ThreadMessageModel messageData)
{

try
    {
        await _findMessageService.AddMessageReply(findmessage);
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Log.Log(EventSeverity.Error, new { Message = "Could not create message", exception });
        throw new Exception(string.Format("Kan ikke opprette melding. {0}", exception));
    }
}


public Task<int> AddMessageReply(FindMessage message)
{
try
    {
        client.Update<FindMessage>(message.Id).Field(x => x.Replies, message.Replies).Execute();
         return Task.FromResult(1);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        log.Log(EventSeverity.Error, "Could not add message and feedback status", exception);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `$http` returns a promise, so [using `$q` is not needed](http://www.codelord.net/2015/09/24/%24q-dot-defer-youre-doing-it-wrong/), that's an anti-pattern. You can try: `return $http.post(url,obj).then((res) => {return res.data;})`

Comment: it doesn't work like that also

Comment: Please show us how you are calling `send` and what `updateThread` does. The second snippet you posted looks fine.

Comment: updated the question

Comment: I have updated code with latest changes

Comment: Read [You're Missing the Point of Promises](https://blog.domenic.me/youre-missing-the-point-of-promises/).

Comment: I'm not sure who identified "duplicates," but I can't see how either one is even remotely a similar question.

Comment: @theMayer thanks. I tried understanding that as well but couldn't understand

Comment: You’re up to 4 reopen votes, so one more and it will be reopened. I suspect we have a golden ticket holder who identified a similar answer on one of the dupes, but that is not a valid reason to flag as a duplicate question.

Answer (score 2):

You should not pass that `scope.updateThread` into the factory, instead you should only return the *$http promise*.

```
commonApp.factory('replyMessageFactory', ['$q', '$http', '$log', function ($q, $http, $log) {

    var factoryObj = {};
    factoryObj.send = function (obj) {

        var req = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: "/api/ThreadMessage",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            },
            data: obj
        };
        return $http(req);
    }    
    return factoryObj;
  }
]);
```

And you will call it like:

```
scope.sendReply = function () {
    replyMessageFactory.send(scope.replyModel)
        .then(function (result) {
            scope.updateThread(result);
        });
}
```

Now your `scope.updateThread` can work syncronously.

---

P.S. care about that typo into `scope.updateThread` parameter, it should be:

```
scope.updateThread = function (obj) {
    getMessages.getMessageById(obj, scope.updateThreadCallback);
}
```

Comment: not working, sometimes it gets the latest and other time it doesn't

Comment: can you show us your code? a working snippet will be good

Comment: I have updated the code now